# Test flask command when using click.confirm("sometext") with abort option

Tags: python, flask, testing, pytest, flask-cli

I want to write a test to the command when the user aborts it, but I have a problem with the `abort` option in `click.confirm`

when i write full command in console
`flask questions deleteall` i got prompt `y/N`.
When i select `N` option user cancel command  and message are displayed in the console `Aborted!`.

It looks like below:

```
Do you want to continue to delete all questions and answers? [y/N]: n

Aborted!
```

The command code is below:

```
bp = Blueprint("questions", __name__)
bp.cli.short_help = "Questions utilities"



@bp.cli.command("deleteall")
@with_appcontext
def deleteall():
    """
    Delete all examples questions and answers from database
    """

    click.confirm('Do you want to continue to delete all questions and answers?', abort=True)
   
    """
    code for command when writing yes in click.confirm - y
    """
```

i have written test below:

```
# full command: flask questions deleteall
# y - select 'y' to confirm deleting  
def test_cancel_deleteall_command(runner, app_with_db):
    result = runner.invoke(args=['questions', 'deleteall', ['N']])
    assert result.exit_code == 1
    print(result.output)
    assert 'Aborted!' in str(result.output)
```

I have a problem with a test that keeps failing because the results are empty.

```
test_cancel_deleteall_command ____________________________________________________________________________________

runner = <flask.testing.FlaskCliRunner object at 0x7fbcf01a5b10>, app_with_db = <async_generator object app_with_db at 0x7fbcf06625c0>

    def test_cancel_deleteall_command(runner, app_with_db):
        # full command: flask question deleteall
        # y - select 'y' to confirm deleting
        result = runner.invoke(args=['questions', 'deleteall', ['N']])
        assert result.exit_code == 1
        print(result.output)
>       assert 'Aborted!' in str(result.output)
E       assert 'Aborted!' in ''
E        +  where '' = str('')
E        +    where '' = <Result TypeError("unhashable type: 'list'")>.output

tests/functional/test_cli_commands.py:28: AssertionError
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Captured stdout call -----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

======================================================================================= short test summary info =======================================================================================
FAILED tests/functional/test_cli_commands.py::test_cancel_deleteall_command - assert 'Aborted!' in ''
```

Does anyone have an idea how to get "Aborted!" command message? I tried with `result.output` but it doesn't work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolve this problem with following code:

```
def test_deleteall_command_when_canceled(runner, app_with_db):
    # full command: flask question deleteall
    # y - select 'y' to confirm deleting
    result = runner.invoke(args=['questions', 'deleteall'], input="n")
    assert result.exit_code == 1
    assert result.exception
    assert 'Aborted!' in result.output
```

i just needed to add `input="n"` because i wanted to simulate user to type `n`

**How i get solve this problem?**

i was check the reference method in the Click library. I was found this line:

```
"code"
    except Abort:
            if not standalone_mode:
                raise
            echo(_("Aborted!"), file=sys.stderr)
            sys.exit(1)
"code"
```

In addition, from the documentation on the Click page in version 8.1.3 I read that:

> If an Abort exception is raised print the string Aborted! to standard error and exit the program with exit code 1.

It turns out that runner.invoke() was badly written.